# Yellow Fever vaccination requirement for Dubai

Tags: dubai, uae, vaccinations, yellow-fever

While travelling from Nairobi to Munich, I have a stopover in Dubai.
Kenya comes under Yellow fever risk countries however I have checked on airlines [website](https://www.emirates.com/in/english/before-you-fly/health/find-health-vaccination-information/) and no vaccination is required however searching on internet states that UAE entry requires Yellow fever vaccination.
I am quite confused now if vaccination is required or not.

I am also wondering if I decide to stay at airport itself then do I still require yellow fever vaccination as I will not be entering the country.

Any guidance here will be helpful.

Comment: According to [TravelDoc](https://www.traveldoc.aero/) Required vaccinations for UAE:  "Passengers aged 9 months and older travelling from or who transited for more than 12 hours through a country with a risk of yellow fever transmission must hold a yellow fever vaccination certificate."

Comment: @Midavalo What is weird is that TIMATIC doesn't state that